# Using join to add a , to the last element in an array in perl

Tags: perl

I have a date array. I am trying to add commas to the elements of the array. I am using join.
I need comma added to the last element. 
Here's my input - 2020 02 20
My output should be - 2020,02,20,

Here's my code

```
@date = join( ',',@date); or @date = join( map "$_,",@date );
```

Bit i can't get the comma on the last element. It would be really great if this can be acheived using only join.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
my $date = join(',', @date, '');
```

i.e. just tell `join` that there's an extra element.

NB: the output of `join` is a single scalar string, not another array, hence `$date` above.

Answer (score 5):

To use the right function for the job - you should use `map` to change all the elements of the array, and the concatenate it all together with `join`

```
my $date = join('', map { "$_," } @date);
```

Comment: But that would take, like, 13 more characters.

Answer (score 4):

> I am trying to add commas to the elements of the array.

```
$_ = "$_," for @date;
```

But if you're trying to create a string rather than modify the array, you can use the following:

```
my $date = join '', map "$_,", @date;
```

The above can be sped up using the following clever yet still readable approach:

```
my $date = join ',', @date, '';
```

Answer (score 3):

To modify all elements of an array, [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) is an appropriate tool:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @date = qw(2020 02 20);
@date = map "$_,", @date;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@date);

__END__

$VAR1 = [
          '2020,',
          '02,',
          '20,'
        ];
```